# How to load Rails.logger in an executable file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, worker

I have an executable file in my rails app, `bin/log_data`. In this file, in order to have access to `Rails.logger` I have to require the following files:

```
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require 'rails/commands'
```

This loads the entire rails environment in this one process that runs `bin/log_data`, and I think the approach is a bit heavy handed. Can anyone share with me how I would just load `Rails.logger` so that I can do `Rails.logger.info('something relatively important to log')?

Also, just some background info, I want to user `Rails.logger` because the output goes to `log/development.log` which is important for what I want to log to be seen in my heroku logs when I tail my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an [`ActiveSupport::Logger`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Logger.html#method-c-new) instance:

```
require 'active_support/logger'
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
rails_env = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development"
logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(APP_PATH + "/logs/#{rails_env}.log")
```

If you really want to call it as `Rails.logger` create a module:

```
require 'active_support/logger'
require 'active_support/string_inquirer'
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(APP_PATH + "/logs/#{rails_env}.log")

module Rails
  class << self
    attr_reader :logger
    attr_reader :env
  end
  self.env = ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development")
  self.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(APP_PATH.join("logs", "#{self.env}.log"))
end
```

Note that it will not have the exacts same setting as the Rails logger when it comes to log levels and formatting which only really can be obtained by starting the rails app.